# "DataBinding: 'index+NewsItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Link'", but property exists (Not a Typo)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

First I have a repeater, and I'm outputting a property.  I have tried both

```
<%#Eval("Link")%>
```

and

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link")%>
```

I have a simple class

```
public class NewsItem  
{  
    public string Link = "";  
    public string Title = "";  
}
```

I populate a List news with with a simple for... each, and then...

```
repeater.DataSource = news;
repeater.DataBind();
```

and I get "DataBinding:  'index+NewsItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Link'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have created fields, not properties

To turn them into properties, adjust your code like this

```
public class NewsItem  
{  
     public string Link { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }              

     public NewsItem()
     {
           this.Link = string.Empty;
           this.Title = string.Empty;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not think it would care about that, but indeed it does.

Comment: I find the constructor unnecessary